# XCode import statement and subdirectories

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

I'm running into an `import` issue that as a relative newcomer to the Objective-C/C++/XCode world I haven't seen before.

I'd like to include this library with my project: https://github.com/jdkoftinoff/jdksmidi

But, it seems like no matter how I try to add it to the project, I get errors when I try to import:
`#import "jdksmidi/world.h"`
(No such file or directory)

I can import without the `jdksmidi` subdirectory, but since inside all of the headers included with the library, the author uses the same syntax with the subdirectory, I'm stuck.

Simplified question: how do I add the library to my project so that I can use the `#import "jdksmidi/___FILE____.h"` format and not throw compiler errors?

Thanks

Comment: In your Xcode tree, does the folder show up in yellow (a link) or blue (an actual folder).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to adjust your User Header Search Paths (USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS) in your build settings. Make sure that the folder containing jdksmidi is in the path.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score -3):

you need add your jdksmidi/world.h file in project, just drag'n'drop it into your groups & files section. Or you can use #include directive